# Sum of product of two combinations

Tags: combinatorics, summation, combinations, binomial-coefficients

I have this

$$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{a-1}\displaystyle\binom{a}{i}\displaystyle\binom{b-a}{a-i}$$

with $b>a$. I used **Vandermonde's identity**,

$$\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{r}\displaystyle\binom{m}{i}\displaystyle\binom{n}{r-i}=\displaystyle\binom{m+n}{r}$$

using $m=a$, $n=b-a$ and $r=a$ and found (correct me if i'm wrong)

$$\displaystyle\binom{b}{a}=\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{a}\displaystyle\binom{a}{i}\displaystyle\binom{b-a}{a-i} =
\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{a-1}\displaystyle\binom{a}{i}\displaystyle\binom{b-a}{a-i}+\displaystyle\binom{b-a}{a}+\displaystyle\binom{a}{a}$$

Then,
$$\displaystyle\binom{b}{a}-\displaystyle\binom{b-a}{a}-\displaystyle\binom{a}{a} =\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{a-1}\displaystyle\binom{a}{i}\displaystyle\binom{b-a}{a-i}$$

but i would like to know if there's any other form to write     $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{a-1}\displaystyle\binom{a}{i}\displaystyle\binom{b-a}{a-i}$ other than this one. Preferably with only one combination.

Comment: The formula counts the number of $a$-selections from two sets containing $a$ and $b-a$ elements ($b$ in total) such that the selection is not contained completely in one of the two sets. Even saying this, I have to mention $3$ numbers (counting results), so I don't think that you will find a simpler formula.

Comment: Note that one of the three numbers is $\binom{a}{a}=1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$S=\sum_{i=1}^{a-1} {a \choose i} {b-a \choose a-i}=\sum_{i=0}^{a} {a \choose i} {b-a \choose a-i}-1-{b-a \choose a}=S'-1-{b-a \choose a}$$
$$S'=\sum_{i=0}^{a} {a \choose i} {b-a \choose a-i}$$
$${b-a \choose a-i}= \text{Coefficient of}~ x^{a-i}~in~~~ (1+x)^{b-a}$$
Multiply by ${a \choose i}$ on both sides
$${b-a \choose a-i}= \text{Coefficient of}~ x^{a-i}~~ in~~~ (1+x)^{b-a}$$
$${a \choose i}{b-a \choose a-i}= \text{Coefficient of}~ x^{a-i}~ in~~~ (1+x)^{b-a}  {a \choose i}$$
Let us sum over $i$ on both sides:
$$S'=\sum_{i=0}^{a}{a \choose i}{b-a \choose a-i}= \text{Coefficient of}~ x^{a}~ in~~~ \sum_{i=0}^{a}(1+x)^{b-a}  {a \choose i} x^{-i}.$$
$$\implies S'=\text{Co-efficient of}~ x^a~ in (1+x)^{b-a}(1+\frac{1}{x})^a$$
$$\implies S'=\text{Co-efficient of}~ x^a~ in (1+x)^{b}={b \choose a}$$
Finally, $$S={b \choose a}-{b-a \choose a}-1$$

Comment: This doesn't acctualy answer the question, because the summation is from $1$ to $a-1$. What you did was basically prove the Vandermonde's identity using algebraic arguments, which is cool, but is not the answer.

Comment: @JTSC  Thanks, I have now edited my answer. You may see it.